# How to add one day to Bootstrap DatePicker when one date is pick in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

Good day Developer, I have two input boostrap datepicker for a user to select and I want if the first date field is selected, the next date field should start from a day plus the start date initially selected on the first date field.
this is my first Input field:

```
<input
  (blur)="setMinDate($event)"
  id="StartTime"
  type="text"
  name="StartTime"
  class="form-control"
  bsDatepicker
  datePickerLuxonModifier
  [(date)]="userFirstInput.startTime"
  [(ngModel)]="userFirstInput.startTime"
  [maxDate]="userFirstInput.endTime"
  [minDate]="startdate"
  [bsConfig]="{ adaptivePosition: true }"
  required
/>
```

this is the second input field:

```
<input
  id="EndTime"
  type="text"
  name="EndTime"
  class="form-control"
  bsDatepicker
  datePickerLuxonModifier
  [(date)]="userSecondInput.endTime"
  [(ngModel)]="userSecondInput.endTime"
  [minDate]="minPickDate"
  [bsConfig]="{ adaptivePosition: true }"
  required
/>
```

the function am applying on first date input in order to store the get the date pick on first input date and add a day to it, which will be use as  [minDate] on the second input date field:

```
minPickDate: DateTime;
    
setMinDate(event){
  this.minPickDate = this.userFirstInput.startTime.plus({days:1});
}
```

But is not working, I try using **ngModelChange and Change** event but it still didn't work out. **Please I need help**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to below using `bsValueChange`, I hope it work for you

```
<input      
  id="StartTime"
  type="text"
  name="StartTime"
  class="form-control"
  bsDatepicker
  datePickerLuxonModifier
  [(date)]="userFirstInput.startTime"
  [(ngModel)]="userFirstInput.startTime"
  [maxDate]="userFirstInput.endTime"
  [minDate]="startdate"
  [bsConfig]="{ adaptivePosition: true }"
  (bsValueChange)= "setMinDate($event)"
  required />
```

ts
minPickDate : date;

```
 setMinDate(value){
    var nextDay = new Date(value);
    nextDay.setDate(nextDay.getDate() + 1);
    this.minPickDate = nextDay;
 }
```

Comment: It work, Thank you for your help. I appreciate.